# <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit" onclick="validatePassword()">Javascript function is not working?

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to match two text box values but my function is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    function validatePassword() {

        var newPassword = document.getElementById('newPasswordTB').value;
        var confirmPassword =document.getElementById('confirmPasswordTB').value;

        if(newPassword != confirmPassword) {
            newPassword.value="";
            confirmPassword.value="";
            document.getElementById('newPasswordTB').focus();
            document.getElementById("confirmPasswordTB").innerHTML = "not same";
        }
    }
</script>

<label>New Password</label>
<input type="password" name="newPassword" id="newPasswordTB"  class="txtField"/><span id="newPassword" class="required"></span>

<label>Confirm Password</label>
<input type="password" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPasswordTB" class="txtField"/><span id="confirmPassword" class="required"></span>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit" onclick="validatePassword()">
```

I want to display a message if `newpassword` and `confirmpassword` is not the same.
Where i am wrong in this code?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what isn't working? - what actually does happen that shouldn't?

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: i want message if newpassword and condirmpassword in not equal

Comment: why are you adding text (not same) in confirm pass..?

Comment: What is happening when you try to run this code? I'd say taking a quick look at it, I'd think that the if block might not do what you want it to. You're setting the value property of two strings, I think you wanted to set the value of the two elements.

Comment: You will need to post your HTML code for us to help you out.

Comment: also use !== instead of !=

Comment: also, setting the innerHTML of a password field will still give you little dots, so no one will be able to read that message you're returning...

Comment: Do you have a submit button that calls your validatePassword() function?

Comment: when i am  tring form is submiting

Comment: id should be unique...

Comment: How exactly is your javascript getting called? There is nothing in your HTML that is invoking the validatePassword function.

Comment: yes i hav submit submit button

Comment: do not down vote if no one want to solve my problem

Comment: Let me create a fiddle for you, and I will see what we can do.

Comment: People downvote a question if necessary information required to solve your query is not provided along with the question. No one is doing you a favour. You are asking for a favour. The problems you can't solve can be solved by others iff the question is clear & understandable. If lack of research is found, down vote the question at very first sight, so that next time you won't commit such mistakes. Everyone goes through this stage in S.O. It's not a big deal. Just chill. @anil kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `innerHTML` to alter the content of a textbox, because it doesn't contain any HTML, like a `DIV`, a `SPAN` or similar. It is called a ["void"](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201005/void_empty_elements_and_self-closing_start_tags_in_html/) element. Also it is a password, so if you put a value in it, the user will not be able to see it. You should put your message in any other place. For example, in the `SPAN` element next to the confirmPasswordTB input:

```
function validatePassword() {
  var newPassword = document.getElementById('newPasswordTB').value;
  var confirmPassword =document.getElementById('confirmPasswordTB').value;

  if(newPassword != confirmPassword) {
    newPassword.value="";
    confirmPassword.value="";
    document.getElementById('newPasswordTB').focus();
    document.getElementById("confirmPassword").innerHTML = "not same"; //Setting message in the SPAN tag
  }
}
```

You can check it working in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w8dt0dnr/1/